# How to handle SelectedIndexChanged event for a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, event-handling

I have `DataGridView` which contains two `ComboBox` columns.
The second `ComboBox` will be filled with data depending on the selected value from first `ComboBox`.

How to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the first `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A great resource for DataGridView questions can be found here:

http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc

From there on how to handle a selected change event:

How do I handle the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Sometimes it is helpful to know when a user has selected an item in the ComboBox editing control. With a ComboBox on your form you would normally handle the SelectedIndexChanged event. With the DataGridViewComboBox you can do the same thing by using the DataGridView.EditingControlShowing event. The following code example demonstrates how to do this. Note that the sample also demonstrates how to keep multiple SelectedIndexChanged events from firing.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        // first remove event handler to keep from attaching multiple:
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new
        EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);

        // now attach the event handler
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new 
        EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }
}

void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected index changed");
}
```

Comment: in this case, if i would like to cell end edit after cb_SelectedIndexChanged. How to not throw error when calling `EndEdit` inside `cb_SelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 14):

If I use `EditingControlShowing` event then `cb_SelectedIndexChanged` fires several times, even when user selects combobox but doesn't change selection.

This works for me:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == comboboxColumn.Index && e.RowIndex >= 0) //check if combobox column
    {
        object selectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
    }
}

//changes must be committed as soon as the user changes the drop down box
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  The only suggestion I have is overload sender and use that, bit less state in the example.  Great example though, thanks a bunch.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. With a little tweaking to limit the selected cell and you have a less hassle to solve. unlike the first code above

Answer (score -1):

Place the second dropdownlist in Update panel like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" >                  
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

set  AutoPostBack="true" property for first dropdownlist like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```