# How to populate the other column when selecting the datagridview combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datagridview

I want to populate the other column when I select the ComboBox in a DataGridView

[This is a pic to make it easier to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNmOV.png)

I manage to select all the "Name" in my database and put it to the 1st column

If I select a data in my DGVComboBox the other column should fill according to my db data.

example
If I pick "Cement" in the first DGVcombobox the second column should be filled with "21".

Comment: You should include what your best shot at populating the DataGridView from the database looked like.

Comment: You need to put in your code that you've tried to get this to work. What you're looking for though is the OnSelectedIndexChanged event for the dropdown. You will just take what the value is and query your database and populate the returned database query value to that field.

Comment: Solution is here - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11955060/2794280](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11955060/2794280)